# Asynchronous wait for an condition to be met

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

In my code I have three variables whose value depend on an external function call, they can be set to true in any moment and in any order, so, they are more like flags.

I need a function to be only once these three variables are set to true.

How can I perform a wait for these three variables to be true, without blocking my server, in an asynchronous way?

(I do not want to be refered to external libraries)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I generally like to use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library for doing things like this, but since you don't want to be referred to external libraries for this.  I will write a simple function that checks it at an interval to see if the variables have been set.

---

**Interval Check Method**

```
var _flagCheck = setInterval(function() {
    if (flag1 === true && flag2 === true && flag3 === true) {
        clearInterval(_flagCheck);
        theCallback(); // the function to run once all flags are true
    }
}, 100); // interval set at 100 milliseconds
```

---

**Async Library Parallel Method**

```
var async = require('async');

async.parallel([
    function(callback) {
        // handle flag 1 processing
        callback(null);
    },

    function(callback) {
        // handle flag 2 processing
        callback(null);
    },

    function(callback) {
        // handle flag 3 processing
        callback(null);
    },
], function(err) {
    // all tasks have completed, run any post-processing.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you control state of these variables - why not trigger some event when you set this variables? Even better - have some object that incapsulates this logic. Something like:

```
function StateChecker(callback) {
    var obj = this;
    ['a', 'b', 'c'].forEach(function (variable) {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, variable, {
            get: function () { return a; }
            set: function (v) { values[variable] = v; check(); }
        });
    });
    function check() {
        if (a && b && c) callback();
    }
}

var checker = new StateChecker(function () {
    console.log('all true');
});

checker.a = true;
checker.b = true;
checker.c = true;
> 'all true'
```

Comment: I was thinking something like this, with get and set, then I've seen your answer :D.

Answer (score 1):

It can be also done with event emitter. I n the example I watch a folder and wait for the following file. One could also use `setTimeout` for demo purposes.

```
const counterEmitter = new EventEmitter();

// wait for the second file before processing the first file
let globalCounter = 0;
chokidar.watch(process.env.WATCH).on('add', (filePath) => {

     globalCounter++;
     const counter = globalCounter;        
     counterEmitter.once('counterEvent', (counterEvent) => {
         console.log('counterEvent', counterEvent);
         if (counter < counterEvent) {
              console.log("I waited", counter)
         }
     });
     counterEmitter.emit('counterEvent', globalCounter)
     ...
```